# Models of Limit Sketches

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, locally-presentable-categories

How do look the categories equivalent to models of finitary and infinitary limit [sketches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sketch_(mathematics)), respectively ?

There are at least $2$ interpretations of the word **finite** here:
the cardinality of the set of cones in the sketch is finite or the domains
of the cones are finite; which is the better understanding ?

It is not obvious to me whether by allowing the word **infinitary** in our chosen meaning creates less or more categories ?
I have some idea, but I would not bet on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A category is equivalent to the category of models of a limit sketch if and only if it is [locally presentable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+category). This is Corollary 1.52 of Adámek–Rosický's [Locally presentable and accessible categories](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/locally-presentable-and-accessible-categories/94CB48295B6AF097FC232313A57BDE17). This restricts to locally $\lambda$-presentable categories and limit sketches with $\lambda$-small diagrams, as noted in the remark following Corollary 1.52 (where $\lambda$ is a regular cardinal). If [$\lambda \trianglelefteq \mu$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sharply+smaller+cardinal), then locally $\lambda$-presentable categories are locally $\mu$-presentable (Theorem 2.11 ibid.), so in this sense, locally $\mu$-presentable categories are more general.